# expected an indented block in pycharm using pygame

Tags: python

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

> File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 12
> running = False
> ^
> IndentationError: expected an indented block

expected an indented block

Comment: `running = False` and the following lines should be indented beneath the `if`

Comment: You have to add spaces before `running = False` and subsequent lines to let python know that this block is inside the `if` statement.  That's what indented block means.

Answer (score 1):

Should it be:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```